# Hoverable elements that have width:0; height:0;

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make an element that allows a user to select an area and that in turn selects a radio button (hidden). The problem is that areas that are selectable need to be triangles, as a result I have used the following code, to create a downward pointing triangle,

```
width: 0; 
height: 0; 
border-left: 26px solid transparent;
border-right: 26px solid transparent;
position:absolute;
top:-1px;
right:1px;
border-top: 26px solid green;
```

My problem is now that it will not do any of the hover behaviour or :checked behaviour, I assuming that this is becase the element theoretically has no dimensions? Is there a work around for this? Basically what I want to happen is when the triangle is hovered it turns grey, when it is clicked it turns yellow and the sibling radio is checked. Here is my fiddle, I have the center (circle working).

http://jsfiddle.net/bfehyv2a/1/

Comment: Sounds like something JS should be handling rather than using a checkbox/radio "hack". Plus, I'm not sure your HTML structure allows for this kind of effect.

Comment: Your borders that create the triangle shapes are on the `div` elements, yet you are trying to hover the `label`s inside them (which have no dimensions _and_ no borders, so there is absolutely nothing to hover at all). And your `div`s still _are_ rectangles – the transparent border parts are still part of their overall shape. So I doubt you will get this to work this way. I would perhaps suggest to use SVG clip paths for this.

Answer (score 1):

try http://jsfiddle.net/bfehyv2a/4/

You will see a :hover still works as the pointer is considered to be over the element when it is on the elements border.

```
.green .long:hover {
    border-top-color: #888;
}
```

Also, notice that `border-top-color` is used as this is the only border you are setting a colour on to create your triangle.

As for :checked status, this only applies to the radio button itself and as the triangles are not within this you won't be able to use this to set there colour. You will have to use JavaScript to set state classes, which is what you should really be doing anyway as it is a better separation of concerns.